# Backreference for regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am trying to find an editor in Android that can backreference regular expressions in substitutions.

If I input the following in the Jota+ editor

```
two one
```

and use the search string

```
(two) (one)
```

it will find the target, but I can not find the replacement string. I have tried

```
\2 \1
```

and

```
$2 $1
```

but they are only interpreted literally.
I naturally wish to obtain the result

```
one two
```

How can I do that with an Android editor app in the phone?

Comment: It works with Android Studio, I just tested it.  Either the editor supports regex replacement or it does not.  Note that what you are trying to do is _not_ a backreference.  A backreference is when you use a capture group in the actual find pattern itself, not in the replacement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you so much. My connection is a little slow now. As soon as it gets better I will try out Android Studio and possibly rephrase question. Thx. // What puzzles me is that it finds the patterns in parentheses but I can not find a way to reference them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I don't understand your reply. I don't think Android Studio comes for Android OS? I wish to edit text in the phone.

Comment: What I am saying is that it definitely works on Android Studio for computers.  Your phone IDE might be more limited.  And again, what you are trying to do here does _not_ involve backrefences, just regular capture groups.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am definitely no expert, but I ask. The \1 \2 or the $1 $2 that are used to reference the captured groups, can't you call them backreferences?

Comment: They are capture groups.  If used in the pattern itself, referring to an earlier captured quantity, then it is also a backreference.

Comment: It worked with the Quick Edit app, so I am good for now. Strange it doesn't work with Jota even though it accepts the parentheses of the captured groups. // I obviously have to check out the definition of backreference and see if I need to rephrase the question.

Comment: @ycc_swe The `$1` / `\1` inside replacement patterns are called [*replacement backreferences*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html), although in Perl they are usually called ["regex-related variables"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) that are filled with values only upon a successful regex match.